# EntityBatch with no ID error when removing items from Accounting Batches

Tags: batches

I have an error when working with Accounting Batches. It's kind of hard to pin down - the front end gives the default / standard / very helpful. What I did was:

- add a new accounting Batch (Contributions > Accounting Batches > New Batch)
- Assign a contribution to the batch
- try to remove the contribution from the batch

at this point I get:

> No response from the server. Check your internet connection and try reloading the page.

message, but ConfigAndLog does give a bit more, i.e.:

```
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Cannot delete EntityBatch with no id."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#2039
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Cannot delete EntityBatch with no id."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php"
    #line: 958
    trace: {
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:958 {
        › if (empty($record['id'])) {
        ›   throw new CRM_Core_Exception("Cannot delete {$entityName} with no id.");
        › }
      }
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Batch/BAO/EntityBatch.php:39 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/Page/AJAX.php:207 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php:266 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/REST.php:550 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:279 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:458 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
      /var/www/html/drupal7/index.php:21 { …}
    }
  }
]


Jan 21 15:24:29  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(433): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(458): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /var/www/html/drupal7/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "rest")
#4 /var/www/html/drupal7/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#5 {main}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss where to go with this - could anyone give any pointers?

I've just realised that this is also happening on a local buildkit drupal-clean. is this a bug?

This is on CiviCRM 5.41.1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What were you trying to do to cause the error?

Comment: Just added to the batch, and then tried to 'remove' the added item.

Comment: ...have updated the Question - sorry - didn't realise I'd not mentioned what I'd done. not ver useful!

Comment: I've also tried this locally on a fresh drupal9-clean install - I get the same issue just by starting a batch, adding a contribution, and attempting to remove the batch @PradeepNayak

Comment: could you try on dmaster?

Comment: I did. same story. will raise an issue in the morning

Comment: Issue raised here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3050

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a regression from [commit#99f7626](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/99f76265c5a462cae4fd59d1a8045492719f7811#diff-0d91c6437ca76cd02208c7c19699d883631d330427a765f4b7ccc323b42ff12d)

Could you try below patch?

```
diff --git a/CRM/Financial/Page/AJAX.php b/CRM/Financial/Page/AJAX.php
index ac2a002c4c..a314f5e736 100644
--- a/CRM/Financial/Page/AJAX.php
+++ b/CRM/Financial/Page/AJAX.php
@@ -170,13 +170,24 @@ class CRM_Financial_Page_AJAX {
         switch ($op) {
           case 'assign':
           case 'remove':
-            if ($op == 'remove' || $op == 'assign') {
-              $params = [
-                'entity_id' => $recordID,
-                'entity_table' => 'civicrm_financial_trxn',
-                'batch_id' => $entityID,
-              ];
+            $params = [
+              'entity_id' => $recordID,
+              'entity_table' => 'civicrm_financial_trxn',
+              'batch_id' => $entityID,
+            ];
+
+            if ($op == 'remove') {
+              try {
+                $id = civicrm_api3('EntityBatch', 'getvalue', $params + [
+                  'return' => 'id',
+                ]);
+                $params = ['id' => $id];
+              }
+              catch (Exception $e) {
+                $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
+              }
             }
+
             break;
 
           case 'close':
@@ -214,9 +225,9 @@ class CRM_Financial_Page_AJAX {
               'status_id' => $redirectStatus,
             ];
           }
-          if ($errorMessage ?? FALSE) {
-            $response = ['status' => $errorMessage];
-          }
+        }
+        if ($errorMessage ?? FALSE) {
+          $response = ['status' => $errorMessage];
         }
       }
     }
```